# How to use imagick's writeImage() function?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

This works if I keep the script in the same directory as the image being manipulated. And the resultant image "foo.jpg" is also generated in the same location.

```
<?php

$im = new imagick('image.jpg');
$im->thumbnailImage( 200, 0);
$im->writeImage("foo.jpg");

?>
```

But what if the script is in one location and the image I wish to work with is in another and the location I wish to save the thumbnail to is somewhere else, how to specify these paths?

Doing something like this doesn't work:

```
$im = new imagick('path/to/image.jpg');
```

Comment: Check the correct namespace, \Imagick if you're using a PSR convention. Or perhaps check case-sensitive names, 'Imagick' instead of 'imagick'. You could also refer to pathinfo(), file_exists(), is_writable() or dirname() with flags, to get proper paths and concatenate with filename. But either way you must set a base directory from which you point to all files. It's up to you.

Answer (score 6):

Might be some file system problem. Try and get a file pointer in php first and check for any problems

```
$fileHandle = fopen("path/to/image.jpg", "w");
```

You can then use Imagick function (version 6.3.6 or newer);

```
$im->writeImageFile($filehandle);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should declare: $imagick= new Imagick('path/to/image'); $imagick->writeImage('path/to/image'); $imagick->close(); $imagick->destroy(); to release all resources.